# WordPress admin: How can I display existing admin sub-menu based on user's role

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I require to show an existing sub-menu item of admin menu based on a specific user role. The role is `general-travel-editor`.

The actual menu layout is like this

> Travel Settings
>   - General settings
>   - Advanced Settings

The above user role is supposed access only the "General Settings" sub-menu. So I want to display the menu for this type users as:

> Travel Settings
>   - General settings

I tried `add_menu_page( 'Travel Settings', 'Travel Settings', 'general-travel-editor', 'general-travel-editor');` but I don't have the option to add the URL of this page.

I am using a VIP plugin.
I need to deliver this by tonight but got stuck!

Somebody please advise how I can do this.

**UPDATE**

User role and capabilities defined in functions.php

```
function general_travel_user_capabilities() {
    $travel_option_caps = array(
        'publish_travel-options'        => true,
        'edit_travel-options'           => true,
        'edit_others_travel-options'    => true,
        'edit_travel-option'            => true,
        'read_travel-option'            => true,
        'delete_travel-options'     => true,
        'delete_travel-option'          => true,
        'read'                          => true
    );

    wpcom_vip_duplicate_role('subscriber', 'travel-option-editor', 'Travel Option Editor', $travel_option_caps);

    $travel_option_caps = array(
        'publish_travel-options',
        'edit_travel-options',
        'edit_others_travel-options',
        'delete_travel-options',
        'delete_others_travel-options',
        'read_private_travel-options',
        'edit_travel-option',
        'delete_travel-option',
        'read_travel-option'
    );

    wpcom_vip_add_role_caps('editor', $travel_option_caps);
    wpcom_vip_add_role_caps('administrator', $travel_option_caps);
}

add_action('init', 'general_travel_user_capabilities');
```

Travel Settings:

```
function travel_setting_pages_init() {
    $travel_settings = travel_create_settings_page(
        'travel_settings_page',
        'Global Travel Settings',
        array(
            'parent'   => false,
            'title'    => 'Travel Settings',
            'position' => '59.4815152342',
        ),
        array(
            'travel_theme_options'   => array(
                'title'       => '',
                'description' => 'Settings that affect all pages of the site',
                'fields'      => array(
                    'mytravel_root_url'   => array(
                        'type'        => 'url',
                        'label'       => 'MyTravel Root URL',
                        'description' => 'The base url for all MyTravel App links',
                        'default'     => 'http://myurl.com',
                    ),
                    'travel_phone' => array(
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'label'       => 'Support Phone Number U.S.',
                        'description' => 'In top left of all pages',
                        'default'     => '800-610-6500',
                    ),
                    'travel_phone_canada' => array(
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'label'       => 'Support Phone Number Canada',
                        'description' => 'In top left of all pages',
                        'default'     => '877-330-3321',
                    ),
                    'travel_weather_text' => array(
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'label'       => 'Alert Text',
                        'description' => 'Text for the alert on the home page. Required for the alert to be displayed.',
                        'default'     => '',
                    ),
                    'travel_weather_link' => array(
                        'type'        => 'url',
                        'label'       => 'Alert Link',
                        'description' => 'Link for the alert on the home page. Required for the alert to be displayed.',
                        'default'     => '',
                    ),
                    'travel_weather_start_date' => array(
                            'type'        => 'date',
                            'label'       => 'Alert Start Date',
                            'description' => 'Start date to display the alert on the home page. Optional.',
                            'default'     => '',
                    ),
                    'travel_weather_end_date' => array(
                            'type'        => 'date',
                            'label'       => 'Alert end Date',
                            'description' => 'End date to display the alert on the home page. Optional.',
                            'default'     => '',
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // Home Page Settings Sub-Page
    $slide_color_options = array(
            'orange-grunge' => 'Orange Grunge Pattern',
            'orange-img1' => 'Orange Image: Truck Engine with Person',
            'orange-img2' => 'Orange Image: Truck Top with Person',
            'orange-img3' => 'Orange Image: Forklift',
            'orange-trailers' => 'Orange Image: Truck Trailers',
            'black-trails' => 'Black Image: Light Trails',
            'dark-grey' => 'Grey Image: Hand',
            'white' => 'White Image: Trucks in Dock',

            'orange' => 'Orange (To be removed)',
            'blue' => 'Blue (To be removed)',
            'black' => 'Black (To be removed)'
    );
    $travel_home_settings = travel_create_settings_page(
        'travel_home_settings_page',
        'Home Page Settings',
        array(
            'parent' => 'travel_settings_page',
            'title'  => 'Home Page Settings',
        ),
        array(
            'travel_home_slideshow_settings' => array(
                'title'       => 'Home Slideshow Settings',
                'description' => 'If image is not set, slide will not be shown.',
                'fields'  => array(
                    // Slide 1
                    'slide_color_1'   => array(
                        'type'    => 'radio',
                        'label'   => 'Slide 1 Background Color',
                        'default' => 'orange',
                        'options' => $slide_color_options
                    ),
                    'slide_image_1'   => array(
                        'type'        => 'media',
                        'label'       => 'Slide 1 Image',
                        'description' => 'Transparent PNG @ 911x375. See travel-home-marquee-template.psd',
                    ),
                    'slide_heading_1' => array(
                        'type'        => 'textarea',
                        'label'       => 'Slide 1 Heading',
                    ),
                    'slide_sub_heading_1' => array(
                        'type'        => 'wysiwyg',
                        'label'       => 'Slide 1 Sub-Heading',
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'travel_home_mid_cta_settings' => array(
                'title'   => 'Middle CTA Settings',
                'fields'  => array(
                    'mid_cta_heading_1_1' => array(
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'label'       => 'Middle CTA 1 - First Line',
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'travel_home_lower_cta_settings' => array(
                // first block
                'title'   => 'Lower CTA Settings',
                'fields'  => array(
                    'lower_cta_image_1'   => array(
                        'type'        => 'media',
                        'label'       => 'Lower CTA 1 - Header Image',
                        'description' => 'Transparent PNG @ 193x71. If set, overrides main heading text.',
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'travel_setting_pages_init' );
```

`travel-option` is a Custom Post Type so I could use it in `caps` array. When logging in with the said user role I can see the CPT menus are coming up nicely but how can I add this settings menu? I apologize for posting such a long code!

Answer (score 1):

I will leave another answer here for anyone facing the same situation.

For me, I was creating a plugin and wanted to give it a role different than (Administrator)

I searched for the already existing wp roles and chose "Author" role. [Roles are mentioned in this link](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/)

Here's how I added my menu =>

`add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu title', 'upload_files', 'url slug', 'function name to be executed', $logo , 1 );`

So you just have to replace the 'upload_files' with any other capability matching the selected role.

Answer (score 0):

The add_submenu_page function - which you should use for "advanced settings" is defined like this:

> add_submenu_page( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string
>   $menu_title, **string $capability**, string $menu_slug, callable $function
>   = '' );

As you can see you can define a certain `$capability` for displaying your menu or submenu page.

You can either use a capability which is only available to admins like `manage_options` or you could even define a special capability like this:

```
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_advanced_travel_settings' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

If you do it correctly the advanced page should only be visible to users whom you have granted this capability.

Note: Within the custom admin page callback - for security reasons - you should also check if the current user has the required capability.

```
if(current_user_can('edit_advanced_travel_settings')) {
// display page
} else {
echo "Sorry advanced travel settings are not available to you.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since I already have a role and its capabilities defined do I need to define it again? One thing I forgot to mention that this is not a post type, its a custom settings page. How can I `add_cap` to it?  I have updated my original question with more detail. Would be grateful if you please explain a bit more.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. How would I add the Page URL in 'add_submenu_page` function? I am a beginner to WP. Sorry if all my queries look stupid!

Comment: It will be really helpful for you reading this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities. You are not adding a cap to the page but you may create a cap whose only purpose is the permission to see this editing page.

But as already said the manage_options capability is probably sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: Also read the docs regarding add_submenu_page: They will explain adding the page_url in detail (see the comments) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/